# How to apply left padding to account number in java

Tags: java

I have account number with `09` or `10` or `11` digits. Account numbers are loading dynamically from database.

I want to display `327231123` to `xxxxx1123` or `32145678910` to `xxxxxxx8910`.

I want to replace all digits with 'x' leaving the last four digits.

Account number datatype is `String`

Comment: Do you want to replace last four digits with X? Or you actually meant that you want to replace all digits with X leaving the last four digits?

Comment: Not last four digits,remaining digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
String xs = new String(new char[accountNumber.length() - 4]).replace("\0", "X");
String lastFourDigit =  accountNumber.substring(accountNumber.length() - 4);

String result = xs + lastFourDigit
```

Example:
input: `327231123`
output:  `XXXXX1123`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.replaceAll` method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("327231123".replaceAll("\\d{5}", "*****"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Study about String#replace() method.
Also you can try with simple for loop.

```
    String accountNumber = "327231123";
    String replacedByX = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < accountNumber.length() - 4; i++) {
        replacedByX += "x";
    }
    replacedByX += accountNumber.substring(accountNumber.length() - 4);
```

http://ideone.com/sd11nY